# Error in train.default

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification

I am trying to build a classifier code but I am having some issues with the training parameters

my label parameter is " Class "

Here is my code and snippet of my data

```
# load the library
library(mlbench)
library(caret)
# load the dataset
titanicDF <- read.csv(file="C:/Users/yobo/Desktop/Full_Dataset2.csv", header=TRUE, sep=",")
head(titanicDF)

id   length width petal_length sepal_length Class
1  1        3423   17.2.2       17.2.2   0
1  1        3223   11.2.2      17.2.2   0
1  1        3223   10.2.2     21.2.2   1
1  1        3123   16.2.2     22.2.2   1
1  1        344   14.2.2     24.2   1
1  1        3456   15.2.2     65.2.2   1
1  1        3112   12.2.1    14.2.2   0
# prepare training scheme
control <- trainControl(method="repeatedcv", number=10, repeats=3)
    # train the LVQ model
    set.seed(7)
   modelLvq <- train(titanicDF$Class, data=titanicDF, method="lvq", trControl=control)
```

I got this error:

```
Error in train.default(titanicDF$Class, data = titanicDF, method = "lvq",  : 
  argument "y" is missing, with no default
```

i tried

```
> modelLvq <- train(data$Class, data=titanicDF, method="lvq", trControl=control)
Error in data$Class : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable
```

That still gave another error. What is the issue?

Comment: You should check in the documentation but I'm pretty sure that for `caret` as most R packages when you specify `data`, you don't need to then use `titanticDF$Class`, just use `Class` i.e. `train(Class, data=titanicDF, method="lvq", trControl=control)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
modelLvq <- train(Class~width+petal_length+sepal_length, data=titanicDF, method="lvq", trControl=control)
```

You need to specificity the formula so the model knows how to do the classification.

Comment: my label is just Class  so will I need to specify all the other parameters?

Comment: Yes, it has to know what features you want to consider in respect to that Class.